# Android video view should be in landscape mode by default

Tags: android, android-layout, video

In my app i am displaying videos from Vimeo and Youtube. All videos should be open in Landscape Mode by default. Whole App is on Portrait orientation based only.Video is playing in portrait mode only. not playing in Landscape Mode and also not supporting orientation.

i am using the following code.

```
Ext.getCmp('videoPageView').setHtml('<!DOCTYPE HTML"><html><body><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video'+video+'" height="270px" width="100%" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></body></html>');
```

Comment: can you post the xml code?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the AndroidManifest.xml within the activity where you show your video in:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.example.MyApp.MyScreen"
  android:label="@string/title_activity"
  android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
</activity>
```

If that doen't fix your problem, try to add this in the xml of the activity where you show your video's (in the parent layout, probaply just a LinearLayout):

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the orientation in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivtyName"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"  
           >
</activity>
```

this will force the activity to be in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to your  tag in the manifest for the specific activity that you want to be in landscape.